# R 3.2.1, reverse colors on map

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

Here is part of R code

```
# create a new grouping variable
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Lower Third", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 55, "Upper Third", "Middle Third"))

# get the map
bbox <- make_bbox(sep$Longitude, sep$Latitude, f = 0.3)
map <- get_map(bbox)


# plot the map and use the grouping variable for the fill inside the aes
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=5, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=c("Upper Third", "Middle Third","Lower Third"), values=c("green","orange","red"))
```

But instead of the map making

"Upper Third" correspond with Green
"Middle Third" correspond with Orange
"Lower Third" correspond with Red

The color scheme is mixed up, i.e. Upper Third corresponds with Red, and Lower Third corresponds with Green.

Higher numbers = good = green, but the map shows opposite. How to fix this?

[image]

## What I tried so far

The following code

```
# create a new grouping variable
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Lower Third", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 55, "Upper Third", "Middle Third"))
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- factor(Percent_SEP12_Assets)
levels(Percent_SEP12_Assets) <- c("Upper Third", "Middle Third", "Lower Third")


# get the map
bbox <- make_bbox(sep$Longitude, sep$Latitude, f = 0.3)
map <- get_map(bbox)


# plot the map and use the grouping variable for the fill inside the aes
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=9, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","orange","red"))
```

Will give this, which corrects the data labels, but the points in the map are inverted, i.e. where it is green it is red and vice versa (points in blue circle should be red)

[image]

But when I reversed "red" and "green" in original code, it works (area in blue circle supposed to be red), but I believe this is a "band-aid" approach

```
# create a new grouping variable
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Lower Third", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 55, "Upper Third", "Middle Third"))

# get the map
bbox <- make_bbox(sep$Longitude, sep$Latitude, f = 0.3)
map <- get_map(bbox)


# plot the map and use the grouping variable for the fill inside the aes
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=9, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=c("Upper Third", "Middle Third","Lower Third"), values=c("red","orange","green"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn `Percent_SEP12_Assets` into a factor variable and specify the order of the levels:

```
# create a new grouping variable
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Lower Third", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 55, "Upper Third", "Middle Third"))
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- factor(Percent_SEP12_Assets,
                               levels = c("Upper Third", "Middle Third", "Lower Third"))


# get the map
bbox <- make_bbox(sep$Longitude, sep$Latitude, f = 0.3)
map <- get_map(bbox)


# plot the map and use the grouping variable for the fill inside the aes
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=5, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","orange","red"))
```

Comment: You mean turn `Percent_SEP12_Assets` into factor variable after making it a group variable with `Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Lower Third", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 66, "Upper Third", "Middle Third"))` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I changed my answer to just that.

Comment: Still not working :-( However if I switch "red" with "green" in my individual code, then it works. Your code looks correct, why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: The display changes, i.e. green corresponds to Upper Third, but the data points on map are incorrect. Will post details in original post

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I hadn't tested the code because I didn't have the data. I edited my answer. You need to specify the levels within the factor function.

Comment: Now its working. Before, levels was outside of factor, now it is within