# R 3.2.1 incorrect mapping of color

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

This is based on [R 3.2.1, reverse colors on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272710/r-3-2-1-reverse-colors-on-map)

I have two data points, one is more than 66%, which should be green, other is less than 33%, which should be red.

However, the less than 33% is orange.

Below is the code, which looks correct (but something is wrong)

```
sep <- read.csv("Out_SEP_assets_csv.csv")
Sub1 <- sep[grep("SEP.12", names(sep))]
sep$newCol <- 100*rowSums(Sub1)/rowSums(sep[4:7])

# create a new grouping variable
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Less than 33%", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 66, "More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%"))
Percent_SEP12_Assets <- factor(Percent_SEP12_Assets,
                               levels = c("More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%", "Less than 33%"))


# get the map
bbox <- make_bbox(sep$Longitude, sep$Latitude, f = 1)
map <- get_map(bbox)


# plot the map and use the grouping variable for the fill inside the aes
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=9, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","orange","red"))
```

The dput(sep) is

```
structure(list(School = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Out of City\\00L001", 
"Out of City\\O308"), class = "factor"), Latitude = c(40.821367, 
41.310426), Longitude = c(-73.488313, -73.837612), Windows.SEP.11 = c(4L, 
69L), Mac.SEP.11 = 0:1, Windows.SEP.12 = c(3L, 26L), Mac.SEP.12 = c(16L, 
1L), newCol = c(82.6086956521739, 27.8350515463918)), .Names = c("School", 
"Latitude", "Longitude", "Windows.SEP.11", "Mac.SEP.11", "Windows.SEP.12", 
"Mac.SEP.12", "newCol"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Output is this (incorrect circled in red) ........ How to fix?

[image]

## Responses

Coordinates are correct, I am asking why is the point incorrectly colored. I thought this logic is correct

`Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Less than 33%", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 66, "More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%"))`

## Updated code

I tried this per @bondeded user and resulting map is same as before

```
sep <- read.csv("Out_SEP_assets_csv.csv")
Sub1 <- sep[grep("SEP.12", names(sep))]
sep$newCol <- 100*rowSums(Sub1)/rowSums(sep[4:7])



# create a new grouping variable

sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Less than 33%", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 66, "More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%"))
sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets <- factor(sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets,
                               levels = c("More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%", "Less than 33%"))


# get the map
bbox <- make_bbox(sep$Longitude, sep$Latitude, f = 1)
map <- get_map(bbox)


# plot the map and use the grouping variable for the fill inside the aes
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=9, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","orange","red"))
```

## Actual CSV

Here is actual CSV, two rows

```
School               Latitude   Longitude   Windows-SEP-11  Mac-SEP-11  Windows-SEP-12  Mac-SEP-12
Out of City\00L001  40.821367   -73.488313  4   0   3   16
Out of City\O308    41.310426   -73.837612  69  1   26  1
```

Comment: Maybe you can use instead < than.

Comment: @user792000 Coordinates are correct. But the point must be red, not orange, hence output from `dput`

Comment: @user792000 Tried `<` instead of `<=` it doesn't work

Comment: @choff Perhaps you can help troubleshoot this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default `ggplot2` drops unused levels from factors. There are two options:

Specify `drop = FALSE`

```
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=9, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","orange","red"), drop = FALSE)
```

Specify the values for each level:

```
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=9, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(`More than 66%` = "green", `Between 33% and 66%` = "orange", `Less than 33%` = "red"))
```

Clearly you could also do both.

Answer (score 1):

Now I got what you meant. The problem is in you ifelse structure. Maybe this can help:

```
ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Less than 33%", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 66, "More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%"))
    [1] "More than 66%" "Less than 33%"
```

Comment: Ok, your dput data is not that reproducible, beware.

Comment: I think you should delete this answer. It's just wrong.

Comment: That is really true @bondeddust. It'd give inverse values. But the point made in my answer was that the issue was the ifelse structure.  Thanks saying that.

Comment: @user792000 How is dput data not reproducible? How to make is reproducible?

Comment: @user792000 What is wrong with the structure of the `ifelse` statement? It looks fine to me.

Comment: I think this it's fine.

Comment: @user792000 this doesn't fix the problem which is more to do with ggplot's handling of factors